# Partial Updates using EF Core to CosmosDB

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to do partial updates using EF Core and Cosmos DB?
I want to add an item to an existing array without retrieving the entire document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Partial document update](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update)is not currently supported in Entity Framework.

This is on their current roadmap. Feel free to upvote it on the EF GitHub repo, [Cosmos: Allow partial updates](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13559)